# Kotlin Firebase Groupie RecyclerView Scrolls to Top when like Button Pressed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am an iPhone developer and currently porting my app to Android with Kotlin language and this is my first android app so I do not know about the Android studio or Kotlin much so bare my question.

I have an app where I show all the images stored into the firebase and each image has like node. So when the users pressed the like button the user Id will be added to the node and pressing the button again will remove the user Id from the firebase node. I use Groupie RecyclerView for the images to for rows. The only problem is when I click the like button the RecyclerView scrolls to the top which is kind of irritating and not a good user interface. How can I stop the like button to stop scrolling to the top, I believe its due scrolling due to firbase database refreshing the RecyclerView.

Below is the function I have used for fetching the data from the database

```
 private fun fetchFactsFromFirebase(){
    val factsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Facts").orderByChild("/timestamp")
    factsDb.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
            p0.children.forEach {
                val facts = it.getValue(Facts::class.java)
                if (facts != null) {
                    adapter.add(FactsItems(facts))
                }
            }
            recycleview_facts.adapter = adapter
        }
```

Below is the facts class I have used to bind my database to the Row

```
class FactsItems(val facts: Facts) : Item<ViewHolder>(){
val factsId : String = ""


val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid

override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.textview_facts.text = facts.captionText
 Picasso.get().load(facts.factsLink).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_image).into(viewHolder.itemView.imageview_facts)
    viewHolder.itemView.likeview_facts.text = facts.likes.count().toString()
    val likeButon = viewHolder.itemView.like_facts_image_button
    if (facts.likes.contains(currentUser!!)){
        likeButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.like)
        likeButon.isSelected = true
    }else{
        likeButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nolike)
        likeButon.isSelected = false
    }
    viewHolder.itemView.imageview_facts
    viewHolder.itemView.like_facts_image_button.isSelected
    viewHolder.itemView.like_facts_image_button.setOnClickListener {
        if (likeButon.isSelected == true){
            likeButon.isSelected = false
            likeButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.nolike)
            addSubtractLikes(false,position, viewHolder)
        }else {
            likeButon.isSelected = true
            likeButon.setImageResource(R.drawable.like)
            addSubtractLikes(true, position, viewHolder)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the addSubtract function to add or subtract the likes of the user ignore the postion and view holder I just tried to get the postion in this function but it did not work.

```
fun addSubtractLikes(addlike: Boolean, position: Int, viewHolder: ViewHolder){
    val currentUsers = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    if (addlike){
        facts.likes.add(currentUsers!!)
        Log.d("Like","User Liked ${currentUsers}")

    }else {
        facts.likes.remove(currentUsers!!)
        Log.d("Like","User DisLiked ${currentUsers}")
    }

    val likeRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/Facts").child(facts.factsId).child("/likes")
    likeRef.setValue(facts.likes)
    Log.d("Like","liked Users ${facts.likes}")
}
```

What all I have tried.

When I get the instance of the RecyclerView into the factsItem class it gives me an error `nullPointerException`
so i cannot use `RecyclerView.scrollToPostion` or RecyclerView any function

Thank you any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour even if you aren't using `Groupie`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried without groupie.   Ahh lets get doing that

Comment: Tell me if it works without it.

Comment: no it did not work